# Event between X clicked/alt-F4 and windowsclosing() event

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm making a application with a main JFrame and some threads. I use a windowslistener on my frame to detect for the closing event. But sometimes when i close the application (closing the mainframe), there is delay due to the threads. it appears that swing wait for all thread finish before calling the windowsclosing() function. That delay can be a bit long (1-30seconds) so i would like to show a messagedialog "closing" like eclipse because for the user it seems that the application is not responding.

How can i get the event when the user attemp to close the windows not when the windows is actually closing ?

Sorry for my english :)

Thks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You should close you threads manually.
And there is two events callbacks: WindowClosing and WindowClosed

Comment: I dont want to close my threads i want them to finish normally. I dont want to change the mecanism it's great the way it is, i just want to warm the user that the application is closing and he must wait a bit. The events windowclosed occurs after WindowClosing